# Print subfigure range in caption

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img1}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image.jpg}}%
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img2}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image.jpg}%
}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This works all fine, but what I wont to achieve is that the main caption automatically gives me the range of subfigures (never mind the subcaptions here). So instead of `Figure 1` in this case, I want LaTeX to print `Figure 1a–b` (and if there are more subfigures, adapt accordingly).

So far, I redefined the caption by hand with `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}a--b}`, but I'd like to have this automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patching into `\subcaptionbox` this can be achieved with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionFirst{}
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionLast{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionRange
  {%
    \MySubcaptionFirst
    \ifx\MySubcaptionLast\@empty
    \else
      --\MySubcaptionLast
    \fi
  }
\newcommand*\SubCaptionBoxPatch
  {%
    \ifx\MySubcaptionFirst\@empty
      \expandafter\def\csname the\@captype\endcsname
        {\arabic{\@captype}\MySubcaptionRange}%
      \edef\MySubcaptionFirst{\csname thesub\@captype\endcsname}%
    \else
      \edef\MySubcaptionLast{\csname thesub\@captype\endcsname}%
    \fi
  }
\apptocmd \caption@iiibox 
  {\SubCaptionBoxPatch} 
  {}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img1}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img2}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img3}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img1}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}%
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img3}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}%
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img3}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}%
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick as described in my question. After playing a bit with it, I realised that this gives me all kind of problems with my `cleveref` references in the text and with `koma-scrip's` `besidecaption`. I guess, an automated solution which would take care of all thins things would get too complex.

Comment: @Simifilm yes it changes the references. One could change that by redefining how the caption label is printed instead of the numbering format of the counter. Don't know the internals of `besidecaption`, so I would need some time to make out how to make it compatible with it (if possible -- well with a two run solution almost anything is possible). I don't think I'll invest that much time though.

Comment: @Simifilm can you provide an example with `cleveref` where it's messing up and an example wtih `besidecaption` in a follow up question? This way you might get answers which are automated and compatible with those two constructs. And I (might) have more spare time this evening, so you'd provide me with something to do :)

Comment: I posted a follow-up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451710/subfigure-range-in-caption-with-cleveref-and-besidecaption

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option which uses cleveref to format the label range. You only have to specify the first and last label you assigned to the subfigures.

[image: subfigures]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefrangeformat{figure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
\newcommand{\subfigurecaption}[3]{%
    \begingroup
        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\crefrange{#1}{#2}}
        \caption{#3}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img1}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}%
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img2}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
}
\subfigurecaption{fig:img1}{fig:img2}{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}

\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img3}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}%
\subcaptionbox{}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}%
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img4}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
}
\subfigurecaption{fig:img3}{fig:img4}{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that something along this line was possible, but can't this be even more automated? That`\caption` checks whether there are any subfigures and automatically gets redefined?

Comment: @Simifilm Maybe it could, but then you would end up with a completely custom way to specify figures because I do not know of any way to derive that from the standard input format. But maybe someone else will have an idea that would be a bit less invasive.

Comment: @TeXnician Idea? yes! Less invasive? no.

Comment: @Skillmon +1 nonetheless, because automation with TeX is always nice :)