# Subfigure range in caption with cleveref and besidecaption

Tags: captions, koma-script, subfloats, subcaption, cleveref

I [originally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451199/print-subfigure-range-in-caption/451203) asked for a solution which would automatically give me the range of subfigures in a caption. Skillmon came up with something which did work with my original MWE, but which gives problems with `cleveref` and `besidecaption` (from `komascript`).

Here's the new MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionFirst{}
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionLast{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionRange
  {%
    \MySubcaptionFirst
    \ifx\MySubcaptionLast\@empty
    \else
      --\MySubcaptionLast
    \fi
  }
\newcommand*\SubCaptionBoxPatch
  {%
    \ifx\MySubcaptionFirst\@empty
      \expandafter\def\csname the\@captype\endcsname
        {\arabic{\@captype}\MySubcaptionRange}%
      \edef\MySubcaptionFirst{\csname thesub\@captype\endcsname}%
    \else
      \edef\MySubcaptionLast{\csname thesub\@captype\endcsname}%
    \fi
  }
\apptocmd \caption@iiibox 
  {\SubCaptionBoxPatch} 
  {}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}%
      {\emph{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}}
\crefrangelabelformat{subfigure}%
      {\emph{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img1}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image.jpg}}%
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img2}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image.jpg}}
 \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img3}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image.jpg}}%
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img4}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image.jpg}}
\begin{captionbeside}
{Caption}
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img5}}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image.jpg}}
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
\crefrange{fig:img1}{fig:img4}
\end{document}
```

There are several problems here:

- This produces errors when compiling (`Argument of \@cref@firsttok has an extra }.`)
- The reference produced by `cleveref` is wrong. It should be `1a–d`, but it is instead `1a––cd`.
- The caption is missing the subcaptionbox in the the `captionbeside` environment and therefore only prints `1a–d` instead of `1a–e`.

I more or less understand what is happening in the the case of `captionbeside`, but the interaction with `cleveref` is beyond me.

Comment: The issue in `captionbeside` is easy to understand as the changes made to `\MySubcaptionLast` are made local and don't have any effect if used inside `captionbeside`. A more complicated setup with global defs and a reset at the start and end of the `figure` or `table` environments would solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version which does work with your MWE. I changed the way it works to using global definitions and not changing the formatting of the counter it's used for but by changing the way the `caption` package does print its caption labels.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{duckuments}% random pictures not every time the same, totally useless for serious documents

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\ClearMySubcaptionThings}
\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\ClearMySubcaptionThings}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\ClearMySubcaptionThings}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\ClearMySubcaptionThings}
\newcommand*\ClearMySubcaptionThings
  {%
    \gdef\MySubcaptionFirst{}%
    \gdef\MySubcaptionLast{}%
  }
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionFirst{}
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionLast{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionRange
  {%
    \MySubcaptionFirst
    \ifx\MySubcaptionLast\@empty
    \else
      --\MySubcaptionLast
    \fi
  }
\newcommand*\SubCaptionBoxPatch
  {%
    \ifx\MySubcaptionFirst\@empty
      \xdef\MySubcaptionFirst{\csname thesub\@captype\endcsname}%
    \else
      \xdef\MySubcaptionLast{\csname thesub\@captype\endcsname}%
    \fi
  }
\apptocmd \caption@iiibox 
  {\SubCaptionBoxPatch} 
  {}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}
\makeatother
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subcaptions}
  {#1 #2\MySubcaptionRange}
\captionsetup{labelformat=subcaptions}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}%
      {\emph{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}}
\crefrangelabelformat{subfigure}%
      {\emph{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img1}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img2}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img3}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img4}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}\linebreak
  \begin{captionbeside}{Caption}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:img5}}
      {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
\crefrange{fig:img1}{fig:img4}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Big duck\label{fig:big}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output of multiple subcaptions:
[image]

Output of a single caption (also to show everything is reverted correctly)):
[image]